# Convert ImageSource into IRandomAccessStream

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-contracts

I have loaded image im my app with type `ImageSource`, and I want to share it, but I need to convert image to `IRandomAccessStream`.

**For e.g.:**

```
  ImageSource _myLoadedImage; 
  IRandomAccessStream ras; 
  //Some code when _myLoadedImage convert to IRandomAccessStream 
  RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(ras);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a way to get at the pixel buffer unless it's a WriteableBitmap. If you have the original image data stream/file (ie a png or jpeg) you can use the decoder to get at it and later convert that into an image source. I do something like this in my blogpost here: http://www.iter.dk/post/2012/10/08/Using-User-Provided-Images-for-Secondary-Tiles.aspx

Comment: I have image in .jpeg, and i can conver to BitmapImage. Does it help me? Can i convert this to IRandomAccessStream (without saving file in folders)?

Comment: Yes. Look at the first part of the sample that loads the image with the decoder and then goes through the stream pixel by pixel